# Expert Advisor timefilter doesn't work (mql5)?

Tags: algorithmic-trading, mql5, forex, metatrader5

I can't figure out why my timefilter doesn't work. Let's say I would like to only enter to positions between 7:35-11:30 and 14:30-22:30 and I don't want to enter a position on Friday.

The time filter only works when I create a simple EA with only a trade.Buy function and no other conditions.

The more complex EA should only enter a position when the vaule of the Supertrend indicator becomes higher/lower than the price and only in the given time intervals.

It should close the position at the next sell/buy signal (if it was a buy position then the position should be closed at the next 'sell' signal' ). When closing positions the time interval shouldn't matter it should only mater when entering a new position.

The 'TradingIsAllowed' variable should be 'true' when the current time is in the allowed time intervals but it always returns false for some reason and I  can't figure out why.
It works perfectly fine when I don't use the supertrend and close trades with a simple tp/sl.

Could you please help me?

```
#include  <Trade\Trade.mqh> 
CTrade trade;  

ulong posTicket;
input double Lots=0.1;
int stHandle;
int totalBars;

input ENUM_TIMEFRAMES Timeframe = PERIOD_CURRENT;
input int Periods =12;
input double Multiplier = 3.0;

//for the timefilter
input string StartTradingTime="07:35";
input string StopTradingTime="11:30";
input string StartTradingTime2="14:35";
input string StopTradingTime2="22:30";
string CurrentTime;
bool TradingIsAllowed=false;
bool TradingIsAllowed2=false;


int OnInit(){
   totalBars=iBars(_Symbol,Timeframe);
   stHandle = iCustom(_Symbol, Timeframe, "Supertrend.ex5", Periods, Multiplier);               
   return(INIT_SUCCEEDED);
}

void OnDeinit(const int reason){
}


void OnTick(){
     //for the timefilter 
     datetime LocalTime=TimeLocal();
     string HoursAndMinutes=TimeToString(LocalTime,TIME_MINUTES);
     string YearAndDate=TimeToString(LocalTime, TIME_DATE);
     MqlDateTime DateTimeStructure;
     TimeToStruct(LocalTime, DateTimeStructure);
     int DayOfWeek=DateTimeStructure.day_of_week;

     datetime time = TimeLocal();
     CurrentTime=TimeToString(time,TIME_MINUTES);    
       
   //this should only run if there is a new bar
   int bars=iBars(_Symbol, Timeframe);  
   if(totalBars !=bars){                        
      totalBars=bars;
      double st[];
      CopyBuffer(stHandle,0,0,3,st); 
 
      double close1 = iClose(_Symbol, Timeframe, 1); 
      double close2 = iClose(_Symbol, Timeframe, 2); 
      
      //BUY CONDITION
       if(close1 > st[1] && close2 < st[0]){
           if(posTicket > 0 ){
                 if(PositionSelectByTicket(posTicket)){
                     if(PositionGetInteger(POSITION_TYPE) == POSITION_TYPE_SELL){
                        if (trade.PositionClose(posTicket)){  
                             Print(__FUNCTION__," > Pos ", posTicket, "was closed..");
                         }
                       }
                    }
              }

            if(CheckTradingTime()==true || CheckTradingTime2()==true){
               if(PositionsTotal()==0 && DayOfWeek!=5){
                  Print(__FUNCTION__, " > BOUGHT");
                  if(trade.Buy(Lots, _Symbol)){  
                     if(trade.ResultRetcode() == TRADE_RETCODE_DONE){
                     posTicket= trade.ResultOrder();
                     } 
                    }
                }
              }
           }
            
         else if(close1 < st[1] && close2 > st[0]){
               if(posTicket > 0 ){
                  if(PositionSelectByTicket(posTicket)){
                     if(PositionGetInteger(POSITION_TYPE) == POSITION_TYPE_BUY){
                        if (trade.PositionClose(posTicket))  {  
                        Print(__FUNCTION__," > Pos ", posTicket, "was closed..");
                        }
                     }
                   }
                 }


               if(CheckTradingTime()==true || CheckTradingTime2()==true){
                    if(PositionsTotal()==0 && DayOfWeek!=5){
                        Print(__FUNCTION__, " > SOLD");
                        if(trade.Sell(Lots, _Symbol)){
                           if(trade.ResultRetcode() == TRADE_RETCODE_DONE){
                           posTicket= trade.ResultOrder();
                            }
                         }
                    }
               }
             }
}

 Comment (
            "TradingIsAllowed", TradingIsAllowed, TradingIsAllowed2, "\n",              //TradingIsAllowed always returns false..
            "Current Time=", CurrentTime,"\n",
            "Trading Session1=", StartTradingTime,"-" ,StopTradingTime, "\n",
            "Trading Session2=", StartTradingTime2, "-", StopTradingTime2,"\n",
            "Day of Week", DayOfWeek
            );

}


//trading session 1
bool CheckTradingTime()
   {
   if(StringSubstr(CurrentTime,0,5)==StartTradingTime)
   TradingIsAllowed=true;
   
   if(StringSubstr(CurrentTime,0,5)==StopTradingTime)
   TradingIsAllowed=false;
   
   return TradingIsAllowed;
   }
   
//trading session 2
bool CheckTradingTime2()
   {
   if(StringSubstr(CurrentTime,0,5)==StartTradingTime2)
   TradingIsAllowed2=true;
   
   if(StringSubstr(CurrentTime,0,5)==StopTradingTime2)
   TradingIsAllowed2=false;
   
   return TradingIsAllowed2;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

you dont neet to write "(StringSubstr(CurrentTime,0,5)==StartTradingTime)"
you can write only "CurrentTime == StartTradingTime"